# Prove a multilinear map is differentiable

Tags: analysis, multilinear-algebra

This is how the problem goes:
Let $T:\mathbb{R}^{n_1}\times...\times\mathbb{R}^{n_k}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be multilinear. Prove $$DT(x_1,...,x_k)(y_1,...,y_k)=\sum_{i=1}^k T(x_1,...,y_i,...,x_k)$$

It can be easily proven that bilinear maps are differentiable and $DT(x_1,x_2)(y_1,y_2)=T(x_1,y_2)+T(y_1,x_2)$. However, I got stuck in trying to prove this inductively.

I tried constructing $T(x_1,...,x_k)=g(x_1,f(x_2,...,x_k))$ for some $g,f$ that are multilinear as well. So in the induction step, we can assume $$Df(x_2,...,x_k)(y_2,...,y_k)=\sum_{i=2}^k (x_2,...,y_i,...,x_k)$$
 I also tried using chain rule, but that doesn't seem to go anywhere.

Can anyone help with where to go next?

Comment: Just compute. Let $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$ and $y=(y_1,...,y_n)$. Let me denote by $\Delta$ the right hand side of the formula that you want to prove. Then $T(x+y)-T(x)=T(x)+\Delta + \sum$, where $\sum$ is a sum of terms of the form $T(a)$, where $a$ is formed by taking at least two components of $y$ and the rest from $x$. In each of them, by multilinearlity you can take the components of $y$ out as factors. For example $T(y_1,y_2,x_3,...,x_n)=y_1y_2T(1,1,x_3,...,x_n)$. This means that $T(x+y)-T(x)-\Delta=o(|y|)$. This is almost the definition of differential, therefore $\Delta$ ...

Comment: ... would be the differential if we show that it is linear in $y$. But this is just computing again. $\Delta(ay)=\sum_i T(...,ay_i,...)=a\sum_i T(...,y_i,...)=a\Delta(y)$. And additivity $\Delta(y+z)=\sum_i T(...,(y_i+z_i),...)=\sum_i(T(...,y_i,...)+T(...,z_i,...))=\sum_iT(...,y_i,...)+\sum_iT(...,z_i,...)=\Delta(y)+\Delta(z)$.

Answer (score 4):

Note that since $T$ is linear in each of the  components, we have ${\partial T(x) \over \partial x_i}h_i = T(x_1,...,x_{i-1}, h_i, x_{i+1},...,x_n)$. Since $T$ is linear, the partial is continuous.

Hence $T$ is differentiable and
${\partial T(x) \over \partial x}h = \sum_i{\partial T(x) \over \partial x_i}h_i = 
\sum_i T(x_1,...,x_{i-1}, h_i, x_{i+1},...,x_n)$.

**Alternative route**:

If you want to go full monte, you could note that
$\|T(x_1,...,x_k)\| \le L \|x_1\| \cdots \|x_k\|$ for some $L$. Then note that
(skipping the inductive details)
$T(x+h) = T(x) + \sum_i T(x_1,...,x_{i-1}, h_i, x_{i+1},...,x_n) + \sum_
{\text{terms with }\ge \ 2 h_i}T(\cdots)$.
For $\|h\| \le 1$, we have
$\|\sum_
{\text{terms with }\ge \ 2 h_i}T(\cdots) \| \le K \|h\|^2 $ for some $K$ that depends on $x$, $L$.

Hence $\|T(x+h)-T(x) - \sum_i T(x_1,...,x_{i-1}, h_i, x_{i+1},...,x_n)\| \le K \|h\|^2$, from which it follows that $T$ is Fréchet differentiable with
derivative
${\partial T(x) \over \partial x}h = 
\sum_i T(x_1,...,x_{i-1}, h_i, x_{i+1},...,x_n)$.

Comment: Hi, did you mean summands with at least two different $h_i$ by "terms with $\ge \ 2 h_i$"? I could not understand why you require at least two different $h_i$. Is it sufficient for a summand to contain just one $h_i$ because that summand $\to 0$ as that $h_i \to 0$?

Comment: I meant terms involving the product of two $h_i$a.

Comment: Please explain why you require at least two $h_i$? I'm stuck at that point :(

Comment: So that term is bounded by some constant times $\|h\|^2$.

Comment: Is it enough that that term is bounded by some constant times $\|h\|$?

Comment: No. You need the square. The derivative is the linear part.

Comment: Ah, I seems to get something, but I have to go to the school now :( I will write down my understanding tonight. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I have a question about the chain rule [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3423633/do-i-correctly-understand-the-formula-of-the-chain-rule). Could you please have a look at it?

Comment: Good luck with it!

Comment: Hi, I've just written down my attempt that derivative of a multilinear map is continuous [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3426553/prove-that-the-fr%c3%a9chet-derivative-of-a-multilinear-map-is-continuous). If you don't mind, please have a check on my attempt. Thank you for your help!