# Prove that the derivative of a multilinear map is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, derivatives, linear-transformations, multilinear-algebra

Good evening, I'm doing an exercise about the derivative of multilinear maps:

> Let $E_1, \ldots, E_m$ be normed vector space and $F$ a Banach space. Prove that $\mathcal{L}\left(E_{1}, \ldots, E_{m} ; F\right)$ is a vector subspace of $\mathcal C^{1}\left(E_{1} \times \cdots \times E_{m}, F\right)$.
>   Moreover, for $\varphi \in \mathcal{L}\left(E_{1}, \ldots, E_{m} ; F\right)$ and $\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{m}\right) \in E_{1} \times \cdots \times E_{m}$, we have
>   $$\partial \varphi\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{m}\right)\left(h_{1}, \ldots, h_{m}\right)=\sum_{j=1}^{m} \varphi\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{j-1}, h_{j}, x_{j+1}, \ldots, x_{m}\right)$$

Could you please verify if my proof looks fine or contains logical gaps/errors? Thank you so much for your help!

---

**My attempt:**

Because $E_{1} \times \cdots \times E_{m}$ is finite dimensional, all norms on this space are equivalent. As such, we could endow $E_{1} \times \cdots \times E_{m}$ with the norm $$\|x\| = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^m x_i^2} \quad, \quad x=\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{m}\right) \in E_{1} \times \cdots \times E_{m}$$

We define the map 
$$\begin
{array}{l|rcl}
A_{x} & E_{1} \times \cdots \times E_{m}
 & \longrightarrow & F \\
    & \left(h_{1}, \ldots, h_{m}\right) & \longmapsto & \sum_{j=1}^{m} \varphi\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{j-1}, h_{j}, x_{j+1}, \ldots, x_{m}\right) \end{array}$$

For $h,h' \in E_{1} \times \cdots \times E_{m}$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb K$, we have

$$\begin{aligned}
    A_x(h+\lambda h') &=  \sum_{j=1}^{m} \varphi\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{j-1}, h_{j} +\lambda h_j', x_{j+1}, \ldots, x_{m}\right)\\
 &= \sum_{j=1}^{m} \varphi\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{j-1}, h_{j} , x_{j+1}, \ldots, x_{m}\right)\\
         & \quad + \lambda \sum_{j=1}^{m} \varphi\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{j-1}, h_j', x_{j+1}, \ldots, x_{m}\right)\\
    &= A_x(h) + \lambda A_x(h')
\end{aligned}$$

Hence $A_x \in L(E_{1} \times \cdots \times E_{m}, F)$. Moreover, $A_x$ is the sum of continuous maps, so it is a continuous one. As such, $A_x \in \mathcal L(E_{1} \times \cdots \times E_{m}, F)$. Let $y=x+h$. It follows from the multilinearity of $\varphi$ that $$\varphi\left(y_1, \ldots, y_m\right) = \varphi\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{m}\right)+\sum_{k=1}^{m} \varphi\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{k-1}, h_{k}, y_{k+1}, \ldots, y_{m}\right)$$

and \begin{align}
\begin{split}\label{eq:1} &\varphi\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{k-1}, h_{k}, y_{k+1}, \ldots, y_{m}\right) =\varphi\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{k-1}, h_{k}, x_{k+1}, \ldots, x_{m}\right) \\ &+\sum_{j=k+1}^{m} \varphi\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{k-1}, h_{k}, x_{k+1}, \ldots, x_{j-1}, h_{j}, y_{j+1}, \ldots, y_{m}\right), \quad k=\overline{1,m} \end{split}
\end{align}

Hence \begin{align}
\begin{split}\label{eq:3}
    \varphi\left(y_{1}, \ldots, y_m\right) ={}& \varphi\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{m}\right) + \sum_{k=1}^{m} \Big [ \varphi\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{k-1}, h_{k}, x_{k+1}, \ldots, x_{m}\right)\\
         &  + \sum_{j=k+1}^{m} \varphi\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{k-1}, h_{k}, x_{k+1}, \ldots, x_{j-1}, h_{j}, y_{j+1}, \ldots, y_{m}\right) \Big]
\end{split}\\
\begin{split}\label{eq:7}
     ={}&  \varphi\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{m}\right) + \sum_{k=1}^{m} \varphi\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{k-1}, h_{k}, x_{k+1}, \ldots, x_{m}\right)\\
          &+ \sum_{k=1}^{m} \sum_{j=k+1}^{m} \varphi\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{k-1}, h_{k}, x_{k+1}, \ldots, x_{j-1}, h_{j}, y_{j+1}, \ldots, y_{m}\right)
\end{split}\\
\begin{split}\label{eq:2}
     ={}&  \varphi\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{m}\right) + A_x (h)\\
          &+ \sum_{k=1}^{m} \sum_{j=k+1}^{m} \varphi\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{k-1}, h_{k}, x_{k+1}, \ldots, x_{j-1}, h_{j}, y_{j+1}, \ldots, y_{m}\right)
\end{split}
\end{align}

Moreover, $$\begin{aligned} & \left \| \sum_{k=1}^{m} \sum_{j=k+1}^{m} \varphi \left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{k-1}, h_{k}, x_{k+1}, \ldots, x_{j-1}, h_{j}, y_{j+1}, \ldots, y_{m}\right) \right \| \\ \le & \sum_{k=1}^{m} \sum_{j=k+1}^{m} \left \| \varphi \left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{k-1}, h_{k}, x_{k+1}, \ldots, x_{j-1}, h_{j}, y_{j+1}, \ldots, y_{m}\right) \right\| \\ \le & \sum_{k=1}^{m} \sum_{j=k+1}^{m}  \|\varphi \| \cdot \|x_{1}\| \cdots \|x_{k-1}\| \cdot \| h_{k}\| \cdot \|x_{k+1}\| \cdots \|x_{j-1}\| \cdot \|h_{j}\| \cdot \|y_{j+1}\| \cdots \| y_{m}\| \\ \le & \sum_{k=1}^{m} \sum_{j=k+1}^{m}  \|\varphi \| \cdot \|x\| \cdot \|y\| \cdot \|h_k\| \cdot \|h_{j}\| \\ \le & \sum_{k=1}^{m} \sum_{j=k+1}^{m}  \|\varphi \| \cdot \|x\| \cdot \|y\| \cdot \|h\|^2 \\ =& \|h\|^2\sum_{k=1}^{m} \sum_{j=k+1}^{m}  \|\varphi \| \cdot \|x\| \cdot \|y\| \end{aligned}$$

Finally, $$\begin{aligned} &\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\|\varphi (x+h) -\varphi(h) - A_x(h)\|}{\|h\|}\\ = &\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\left \| \sum_{k=1}^{m} \sum_{j=k+1}^{m} \varphi\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{k-1}, h_{k}, x_{k+1}, \ldots, x_{j-1}, h_{j}, y_{j+1}, \ldots, y_{m}\right) \right \|}{\|h\|} \\ \le&{}\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\|h\|^2\sum_{k=1}^{m} \sum_{j=k+1}^{m}  \|\varphi \| \cdot \|x\| \cdot \|y\|}{\|h\|} \\ =& \lim_{h \to 0} \|h\|\sum_{k=1}^{m} \sum_{j=k+1}^{m}  \|\varphi \| \cdot \|x\| \cdot \|y\|  = 0\end{aligned}$$

As such, $\partial \varphi(x) = A_x$. Next we show that $$\partial \varphi: E_{1} \times \cdots \times E_{m} \to \mathcal L(E_{1} \times \cdots \times E_{m}, F), \quad x \mapsto A_{x}$$ is continuous. We have $$\begin{aligned} \|\partial \varphi(x) - \partial \varphi(y)\| &= \|A_x - A_y\| \\ & = \sup_{h \in E_{1} \times \cdots \times E_{m} \atop \|h\|=1} \|(A_x-A_y)(h)\| \\ &= \sup_{h \in E_{1} \times \cdots \times E_{m} \atop \|h\|=1} \|A_x(h) -A_y(h)\| \\&=\sup_{h \in E_{1} \times \cdots \times E_{m} \atop \|h\|=1} \Bigg \| \sum_{j=1}^{m} \varphi\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{j-1}, h_{j}, x_{j+1}, \ldots, x_{m}\right) \\ &  \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad - \sum_{j=1}^{m} \varphi\left(y_{1}, \ldots, y_{j-1}, h_{j}, y_{j+1}, \ldots, y_{m}\right) \Bigg \| \\ &\le \sup_{h \in E_{1} \times \cdots \times E_{m} \atop \|h\|=1}  \sum_{j=1}^{m} \| \varphi\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{j-1}, h_{j}, x_{j+1}, \ldots, x_{m}\right) \\ &  \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad - \varphi\left(y_{1}, \ldots, y_{j-1}, h_{j}, y_{j+1}, \ldots, y_{m}\right)  \| \end{aligned}$$

It follows from the continuity of $\varphi$ that $$\| \varphi\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{j-1}, h_{j}, x_{j+1}, \ldots, x_{m}\right)  - \varphi\left(y_{1}, \ldots, y_{j-1}, h_{j}, y_{j+1}, \ldots, y_{m}\right)  \| \to 0$$ as $x \to y$

Hence $\partial \varphi(x) - \partial \varphi(y) \to 0$ as $x \to y$. This completes the proof.

Comment: Looks good. ${}{}$

Comment: Thank you so much for verifying my long proof @copper.hat :)

Comment: Hi @copper.hat, I posted a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3433412/compute-partial-j-partialm-fx-in-terms-of-partial-j-1-partial-j-2) about the relationship of total derivative and partial derivatives here. It seems to me that nobody's interested in this question because the algebra of multilinear maps is too cumbersome. Honestly this question reflects my understanding of higher derivative and higher partial derivatives. Could you please have a look at it? Thank you so much for your help!